# Node JS Beginner's CLI Game of Life

Tags: javascript, beginner, node.js, console, game-of-life

I have finished writing my first Node.js app: a CLI app that runs Conway's Game of Life. I am looking for feedback on things that might not have been done the "Node.js way" and what I can do to better improve my understanding of Node.js.

Specifically speaking, looking at the the **game.js** module, is what I am doing following best practices? Is there anything that can be done to enhance this code?

My project can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/cjweiner/conway/tree/bfb94497920fe6f4b1ff86d1168ba33cc18ac401).

**game.js**:

```
var color = require('cli-color');
var fs = require('fs');
var _ = require('underscore');

var clear = function (){
    color.reset;
    process.stdout.write('\033c');
};

function Game(colSize,rowSize){
    var cell = [];
    this.colSize = colSize;
    this.rowSize = rowSize ? rowSize : colSize;

    this.init = function(random, type){
        console.log("init rowSize:" + this.rowSize);
        console.log("random:" + random);
        if(random){
            console.log('hitting random seed loop');
            for(var i=0; i < this.colSize; i++){
                cell[i] = [];
                for(var j=0; j < this.rowSize; j++){
                    console.log("colSize:"+this.colSize);
                    cell[i][j] = {"alive": Math.round(Math.random())};
                }
            }
        }
        else if(type){
            cell = this.getGridFromFile(type);
        }
        else{

        }
    };

    this.run = function(){
        clear();
        console.log('\t\t\t~~~~~~~~~~~~Conway\'s game of life~~~~~~~~~~~~\n');
        this.display();
    };

    this.update = function(){
        var generationCount = 0;
        var timerId = setInterval(function(obj){
            var exit = obj.updateGrid(generationCount);
            if (exit) {
                clear();
                console.log('All cells are dead stopping simulation...');
                clearInterval(timerId);
                return;
            }
            generationCount++;
        }, 500, this);
    };

    this.getGridFromFile = function(type){
        if(type){
            var obj = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./'+type+'.json', 'utf8'));
            return this.parseGridData(obj);
        }
    };

    this.parseGridData = function(data){
        this.colSize = data.length;
        this.rowSize = data[0].length;
        return data;
    };

    this.countNeighbors = function(x,y){
        var amount = 0;
        var rowSize = this.rowSize;
        var size = this.colSize;
        //check for alive cells around current cell
        if(cell[x+1 > size-1 ? 0 : x+1] && cell[x+1 > size-1 ? 0 : x+1][y+1 > rowSize-1 ? 0 : y+1].alive)amount++;
        if(cell[x-1 < 0 ? size-1 : x-1] && cell[x-1 < 0 ? size-1 : x-1][y+1 > rowSize-1 ? 0 : y+1].alive)amount++;
        if(cell[x+1 > size-1 ? 0 : x+1] && cell[x+1 > size-1 ? 0 : x+1][y-1 < 0 ? rowSize-1 : y-1].alive)amount++;
        if(cell[x-1 < 0 ? size-1 : x-1] && cell[x-1 < 0 ? size-1 : x-1][y-1 < 0 ? rowSize-1 : y-1].alive)amount++;  
        if(cell[x+1 > size-1 ? 0 : x+1] && cell[x+1 > size-1 ? 0 : x+1][y].alive)amount++;
        if(cell[x-1 < 0 ? size-1 : x-1] && cell[x-1 < 0 ? size-1 : x-1][y].alive)amount++;
        if(cell[x] && cell[x][y+1 > rowSize-1 ? 0 : y+1].alive)amount++;
        if(cell[x] && cell[x][y-1 < 0 ? rowSize-1 : y-1].alive)amount++;

        return amount;
    };

    this.display = function(){
        for(var i=0; i < this.colSize; i++){
            var line = '';
            for(var j=0; j< this.rowSize; j++){
                if(cell[i][j].alive){
                    line = color.xterm(255).bgXterm(66)(line + '  ');
                }
                else{
                    line = color.xterm(255).bgXterm(255)(line + '  ');
                }
            }

            console.log(color.xterm(202).bgXterm(255)(line));
        }
    };

    this.updateGrid = function(generationCount){
        clear();
        console.log('\t\t\t~~~~~~~~~~~~Conway\'s game of life Generation: '+generationCount+'~~~~~~~~~~~~\n');

        var nextGenGrid = [];

        for(var x = 0; x < this.colSize; x++){
            nextGenGrid[x] = [];
            for(var y = 0; y < this.rowSize; y++){
                var count = this.countNeighbors(x,y);
                var alive = 0;
                if(cell[x][y].alive){
                    //loneliness or overcrowding
                    if(count < 2 || count > 3){
                        alive = 0;
                    }
                    //reproduction or stasis
                    if(count === 3 || count === 2){
                        alive = 1;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if(count === 3){
                        alive = 1;
                    }
                }

                nextGenGrid[x][y] = {"alive": alive};
            }
        }
        if (_.isEqual(cell,nextGenGrid)) {
            return true;
        }
        cell = nextGenGrid;
        this.display();
    };

}

module.exports = Game;
```